# Convergence/divergence of the series $\sum_{n=4}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\log(\log(n))}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms, conditional-convergence

We have the following sum:

> $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=4}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{\log(\log(n))} $$

I have a hunch this series is conditionally convergent, but I get nowhere using the ratio test. What test would be best to apply to this particular series?

Comment: I changed $x\to n$ to have the question body agree with the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just use the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test):

- the function $x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{\log(\log(x))}$ is decreasing,
- as  $x \to \infty$, you have $\dfrac{1}{\log(\log(x))} \to 0.$